# Queries to server during longpolling

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I make longpolling query to, say, `http://polling.site.com/polling`. At the same time I need to make several other queries to server, say `http://site.com/polling/?d=cr`. But they are quenued and are fineshed only when longpolling connection finishes. Picture related
[image]

I use nginx/apache2, php5.

How can I make several queries during longpolling?

Comment: I think most browsers limit themselves to 2 concurrent requests to the same server. http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue

Comment: Longpolling request and second request connect to different subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in the inability to use php session in two connections. So I used `session_write_close` in longpolling loop and at this time second query completes.